# Like Box - Not displaying page feed

Tags: feed, facebook-likebox

I'm a very basic programmer and previously added the like box to a website. At the time it displayed the facebook page feed in real-time and worked great. displaying the facebook page activity feed on the website.

Now, the facebook feed doesnt update. It just displays a few of the old posts (around checkin and some1 commenting on the page) and doesnt load the recent activity feed.

website is http://www.fashiondeli.com.au/news.html

facebook page is this http://www.facebook.com/pages/Fashion-Deli/148941528468961

is it possible that the feed is restrictred due to the page settings??

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: the feed seems to be working fine - the last post is the same both on the site and on the facebook page.

Comment: ok, so i deleted my cookies and it works fine. however, when i log back into facebook and then open the website, it only load 3 news feed items from August. Is it possible that its specific to my facebook settings?   A friend recently liked the page, and it asked him to allow personal data for facebook to access? is this becuase i tried to put opengraph related tags in the information?? i dont need the site to be accessing user details. pls help!

Comment: I viewed the two URLS again from several computers, it all seems to be working.  Do you have some sort of caching plugin installed on your browser? is this behavior reproducible on other computers?

Comment: I have limited time to look at this, but atm, it doesn't work on my mobile, home or and work pc. It appears specific to the fact the website recognises my Facebook acc login. I can print screen what I get and post to tinypic or something if that helps. Also noted that my friend liking prompted him to allow access to his info. Is that cuz of the opengraph info? When I unlike and liked tge page, it didn't prompt me re access to my fb info.. ill test more over weekend. However, if it works for general public I spose that's good enough

Answer (score 1):

I cannot repro this problem.  I see feed items from 15 hours ago on both the Facebook page and the website via the plugin.  Maybe it's a caching issue with your browser or a caching issue with your internet provider.